# Dynamic serie selection on an excel chart

Tags: excel

I have a chart with a lot of series to plot.
Somehow, these series are too numerous, so i want to only plot some of them.
I can do this "statically", by hand, by duplicating the table and removing the unnecessary lines, but obviously, i would prefer something more dynamic, since new series are constantly introduced.

Typically, i want to only draw series which reach a certain threshold, or a certain rank. I can test the condition, and return a result such as 0 or 1 for example.

Now, i don't know how i can use this information to dynamically select the series that will be plotted into the chart. Is it even possible ?

Comment: Are you looking for a pure Excel UI solution? Or are you open to a VBA macro?

Comment: My first preferences goes for a pure UI solution.
Obviously, if this doesn't exist, i will need to consider scripting, but that's much less desirable (scripts are flagged as "virus" in my company).

Comment: There is a difference between VBA (which gives a macro warning) and scripts (such as vbscript) which may be flagged as viruses. I'd be surprised if macros were a major issues as the only time they through up virus like messages is when the VBA code has the potential to self replicate (ie code that can produce further code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach involving a table and its filters. Here is the starting table, series names in first column, categories in first row, last column has some formula testing the values, returning true or false.

Insert a chart using all columns of the table except the last, and you'll probably have to switch rows and columns, so the series are plotted by row.

[image: Unfiltered table and chart]

Click the autofilter dropdown in the header for the test column, and under Number Filters, select Equals, and enter True in the box.

[image: Filtered table and chart]

Your test formula need not return true or false, it may just calculate a function of the values, or whatever you want. Just pick a suitable filter condition to hide what you don't want to show in the chart.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Using dynamic ranges works very well with charts. There are two typical applications for this

1. Using dynamic ranges where the series is known, but the length of the data set for the series is variable.[Stephen Bullen's FunChrt1.zip](http://www.oaltd.co.uk/Excel/Default.htm) is an excellent example of this technique. *No VBA required*
2. When the number of series itself is variable than some basic VBA is required as when a dynamic range is assigned as a sourcedata range it becomes hard-coded (unlike a defined name for a specific chart series which stays "live"). *This sounds like the approach for your query*. Jon Peltier covers this well at [Dynamic Chart Source Data](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/dynamic-chart-source-data/)

Comment: Thanks, i will look into it. Indeed, in my situation, range is known and static, while the number of series to plot is dynamic.

Comment: mmmh, that's very close to my need, indeed.
However, my problem is that i've got a huge number of series, and i want to plot only some of them. I can "flag" which ones, typically using a cell in the same row with a test result (1 would mean "plot me", and 0 "do not plot me").
The problem with the method of Jon Peltier is that it requires all series to be contiguous. I would need a method which either select the series based on a condition, or accept tables with empty rows/columns (i would then dynamically build the table myself using the condition)

Comment: That's a good summary. I would go the table option myself (and I have done exactly that when using this method before). What you could so is (1) build a single table with redundancy, ie summarising all possible rows that may exist (2) build a second table that sorts table 1 by ranking the data that does exist (the `RANK` formula is useful in this regard. In this way the blank rows fall to the bottom and you already have your dynamic range for the existing rows (for example 10 rows from table 1 are non-blnak)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way that requires a little extra data with formulas, but doesn't require VBA.

Suppose Range A has your data. Put a formula in the row above (or below) this range that determines if the range neets the criteria.

Construct Range B, the same size as A, with formulas like:
=IF(A1,A2,na())
where A1 is the test cell for that column of data (i.e., for that column of the chart). If A1 is true, then the value of A2 appears in this cell, otherwise you get #N/A.

Construct your chart using Range B. Any series with #N/A will not be plotted.

To avoid a messy legend, create your chart using range B, but temporarily set all test cells to true so all series appear. Then add a data label to the last point of each series (see [Label Last Point Updated Add-In](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/label-last-point-updated-add-in/)) and kill the legend. Now write the appropriate test formulas.

Answer (score 1):

Another choice, following in the footsteps of the final post here, because I had the same issue.

I have a 'display' area with summary tables and chart.  My source data is on another tab.  I have many series in columns that I want the user to be able to choose to display, these columns are out to the right of my 'display' area.  There are two sets of these series, Range A and Range B

'Display' area running down the right side of the chart I have a list of checkboxes (manually added when series change).  the cell home is set to one cell above the matching series column in Range A.  Range A has a dynamic range to set dates going down the left of Range A using a DMIN and some DMAX formulas.

To avoid the macro sorting issue, I have the second range, Range B is dynamic in that the first column picks up the first 'TRUE' from Range A - set by the associated checkbox.  All pertinent data from the first TRUE including series name is listed below it.  The date Range is simply linked to Range A.

Now with an OFFSET formula for the chart range, from Range B, I have a dynamic number of series, with a chart range set by Range A flowing through Range B to the chart

I have 61 series and can get messy when a user selects 'All' and there are weekly dates for 3 years, but the entire thing only takes 5 seconds to refresh, which is below my user threshold of 6 seconds.

The catch was finding and displaying the TRUE labeled series in order.  My series are in fact grouped, so I want them to stay in order.  The ARRAY formulas slowed me down to 9 seconds, but nested IFs skipping along the Range A TRUE row was faster, down to 5 seconds.  There are reasons for the slow calculation that don't apply here, but the nested IFs were faster than the ARRAYs